# Json to hashMap listview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, hashmap

I'm new to android development. Can you please help me to put my code to the hashmap-listview? Here I am loading bank images to the `ListView`. in my new JSON there is a key and value. ie (BankName , logo)

```
public void ListDrwaer() {
    List<String> listImg = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("bank");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            img_url = jsonChildNode.optString("logo");

            String test1 = img_test_url + img_url;
            listImg.add(test1);
            Log.d("URL", test1);

        }
        ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(getActivity(), listImg);

        menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Error...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pairs instead of HashMap

Try this

```
   public void ListDrwaer() {

        ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> listData = new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("bank");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                img_url = jsonChildNode.optString("logo");
                String test1 = img_test_url + img_url;
                String BankName = jsonChildNode.optString("id");
                listData.add(new Pair<String,String>(BankName,test1 ));

            }
            ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listData);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Error...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```